# Организовать закрытую область с заданиями

Tags: php

Что нужно.

Нужно организовать закрытую область для зарегистрированных участников в которой они участники будут получать задания на выполнение.

К примеру админ публикует задание и цену, далее все это могу обсуждать, кто согласен кто нет.

Я точно помню что есть готовые подобные системы или на половину готовые решения - но не помню как они называются.

Comment: Нужно - организуйте. В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как называется эта CMS или скрипт, есть такой я точно помню. Самому организовывать нужно время.

Comment: Проблема решена, странно что никто не догадался посоветовать - MEMBER AREA скрипты поискать..